# Django - printing variables in templates

Tags: python, django

I created an app called "jobs", basically I'd like to create new "jobs" from the admin console and be able to post it on the jobs.html page.

I created the model and views but I think there is something wrong with the views that doesn't allow me to print the "jobs" on the html template.

Can you please tell me if the error is in views.py?

jobs/models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class post_job(models.Model):
    posizione= models.TextField(max_length=20)
    descrizione= models.TextField(max_length=20)
    requisiti= models.TextField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the MyModelName object (in Admin site etc.)."""
        return self.posizione
```

jobs/admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import post_job
# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(post_job)
```

jobs/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import post_job
# Create your views here.

def viz_job(request):
    posizione = post_job.posizione
    print(posizione)
    return render(request,'jobs/jobs.html',{'posizione':posizione})
```

Comment: Unrelated, but you should follow naming conventions and use CamelCase for your models name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proper answer:

In your views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import PostJob # proper naming

def viz_job(request):
    jobs = PostJob.objects.all()

    return render(request,'jobs/jobs.html',{'jobs': jobs})
```

in your template:

```
<ul>
{% for job in jobs %}
   <li>
      <h3>{{ job.posizione }}</h3>
      <div>
          {{ job.descrizione }}
     </div>
   </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Note that all this is documented.

NB: if you're only interested in those two fields and don't need any of the model's methods, related objects or whatever, you can optimize the query a bit by using a `values` queryset that will yield dicts with the selected fields instead of full model instances:

```
    jobs = PostJob.objects.values("posizione", "descrizione")
```

Everything else remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

You have to know what do you want to return for the template, for example in the views.py :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import post_job
# Create your views here.

def viz_job(request):
    jobs = []
    descriziones = []
    posizione = Job.objects.all()
    for pos in posizione:
        jobs.append(pos.posizione)
        descriziones.append(pos.descrizione)
    context = {
        'posizione': jobs,
        'descrizione': descriziones
    }
    return render(request, 'jobs/jobs.html',
                  context=context)  # this will return context dictonary to the template
```

You can filter and get to fetch specific data from your database

Comment: thank you so much! I implemented 

{% for pos in posizione%}

<p> {{ pos }} </p>


{% endfor %}

and it works. If I may, can I ask how to print all the variables? I mean, "posizione", "descrizione" and so on.. that I made on models.py because like this it prints only the "posizione"  thank you again

Comment: Your welcome and I appreciate that. It's simple to expand and send multiple data to your template I'll update my solution and in the new solution, I'll use array inside dictionary to handle this kind of challenge.

Comment: Parallel lists are an antipattern, and so is retrieving full model instances if you're only interested in a couple fields values.